# Solving a Fibonacci like recurrence in log n time

Tags: algorithm, math

Finding the nth term in Fibonacci series
f(n) = f(n-1) + f(n-2) can be solved in O(n) time by memoization.

A more efficient way would be to find the nth power of matrix [ [1,1] , [1,0] ] using divide and conquer to solve the Fibonacci in log n time.

Is there similar approach which can be followed for 
f(n) = f(n-1) + f(n-x) + f(n-x+1) [ x is some constant ].

Just be storing previous x elements, this can solved in O(n) time.

Is there a better way to solve this recursion.

Comment: That's a nice question, but you'll probably get better answers at math.stackexchange.com

Comment: ...or http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Maybe you could have a look at http://www.cs.uiuc.edu/~jeffe/teaching/373/notes/recurrences.pdf and try to adapt the presented tools to calculate a specific solution for your problem.

Comment: Same way, but the size of the matrix will be x by x. Weather or not this is efficient will depend on the relative sizes of x and n.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As you are already suspecting, this will work very similar. Use the n-th power of the `x * x` matrix

```
|1 0 0 0  .... 1 1|
|1 
|  1
|    1
|      1
|        1
...................
...................
|          ... 1 0|
```

This is easy to understand if you multiply this matrix with the vector

```
f(n-1), f(n-2), ... , f(n-x+1), f(n-x)
```

which results in

```
f(n), f(n-1), ... , f(n-x+1)
```

Matrix exponentiation can be done in O(log(n)) time (when x is considered to be constant).

For the Fibonacci recurrence, there is also a closed formula solution, see here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number, look for Binet's or Moivre's formula.

Comment: Binet's formula isn't O(1) because it contains nth powers that need to be evaluated to a high enough precision.  In practice it is slower than the binary exponentiation of the matrix.

Comment: Note that there is also a closed form solution for this case.  Simply diagonlise the recursion matrix.  Taking the nth power will decouple into `x` scalars being raised to the nth power, and you only need to transform back to the original basis once.  (Well, I suspect this explanation is a bit terse for this forum, but anyway...)

Comment: I thought of this, but is there a more efficient way to do it?
This would take O((x^3)*logn).

Comment: @elricL: Careful with these complexities.  Since the involved numbers get big, we can't assume that – say – an addition is O(1).  Even computing something as simple as 3^n is O(n log(n)).  As to your original question:  Binary exponentiation of the recursion matrix (without diagonalising) is probably your best bet since it will have the same complexity as the solution *with* diagonalising, but the former can be done in integer arithmetic.

Comment: @elricL: You can get do the matrix multiplication in O(x²) with a bit of insight (compute one row in O(x²), then compute the other rows each in O(x))

Answer (score 2):

You may want to look into Tribonacci numbers (and other generalizations of Fiboniacci numbers.) They have been studied quite extensively. See e.g. [Generalizations of Fibonacci numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalizations_of_Fibonacci_numbers)