# Solving non-homogeneous linear recurrence relation in O(log n) time

Tags: algorithm, relation, recurrence

I saw this question about solving recurrences in O(log n) time with matrix power: [Solving a Fibonacci like recurrence in log n time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7686183/solving-a-fibonacci-like-recurrence-in-log-n-time)

The recurrence relations in this question are homogeneous.

Is there a matrix for non-homogeneous linear recurrence relations?

My recurrence is:

a(n) = a(n-1) + a(n-2) + 1, where a(0) = 1 and (1) = 1

The "plus one" makes the linear recurrence relation a non-homogeneous one.

If there is no matrix for this kind of linear recurrence relation, how can I compute a(n) in O(log n) time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write the recursion equation in matrix form for the 3D vectors [ a[n-1], a[n], 1 ]'. The corresponding vector recursion is

```
/  a[n]  \     /  0  1  0  \   /  a[n-1] \
| a[n+1] |  =  |  1  1  1  | * |   a[n]  | 
\    1   /     \  0  0  1  /   \     1   /
```

So that indeed also a brute force matrix exponentiation solution becomes possible.

Answer (score 3):

You need to follow the usual procedure for solving non-homogeneous linear recurrences. First solve the non-homogeneous part for convenient boundary conditions and then solve the homogeneous part.

Experience suggests that the most convenient boundary conditions here are

```
a'(0) = -1 and a'(1) = -1,
```

which leads to the solution `a'(n) = -1` for all `n` of the recurrence

```
a'(n) = a'(n - 1) + a'(n - 2) + 1.
```

Now we write the linear homogeneous recurrence for `b(n) = a(n) - a'(n)`.

```
b(0) = a(0) - a'(0) = 2 and b(1) = a(1) - a'(1) = 2
b(n) = a(n) - a'(n)
     = a(n - 1) + a(n - 2) + 1 - a'(n - 1) - a'(n - 2) - 1
     = a(n - 1) - a'(n - 1) + a(n - 2) - a'(n - 2)
     = b(n - 1) + b(n - 2)
```

By inspection, the solution to `b(n)` is `b(n) = 2 Fibonacci(n + 1)`, so since `a(n) = b(n) + a'(n)`, we have `a(n) = 2 Fibonacci(n + 1) - 1`.

Comment: Okay, so b(0) = 2, b(1) = 2 and b(n) = b(n - 1) + b(n - 2). But, why b(n) = 2 Fibonacci(n + 1)? Assuming this is true, I can understand why a(n) = 2 Fibonacci(n + 1) - 1, but this inspection that leads b(n) to 2 Fibonacci(n + 1), I didn't understand...

Comment: @matheuscscp It satisfies the Fibonacci recurrence `b(n) = b(n - 1) + b(n - 2)`, with slightly different boundary conditions. Fibonacci starting at 1 is 1, 1, and this is 2, 2, so it's twice the shifted Fibonacci sequence.